# Finding Euclidean Normal Form of an Isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $$A = \frac{1}{4} \left(\begin{matrix}  \sqrt 3 + 2 & \sqrt 3 - 2 & -\sqrt 2 \\ \sqrt 3 - 2 & \sqrt 3 + 2 & - \sqrt 2 \\ \sqrt 2 & \sqrt 2 & 2\sqrt 3 \end{matrix} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}.$$
Prove that $\phi: x \mapsto Ax$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is an isometry. Find the Euclidean normal form $B$ of $A$ and an orthogonal matrix $S\in O(3)$ such that $B=S^{-1}AS$.

Proving that $\phi$ is an isometry is simply verifying that $A^TA=AA^T= I$.

Now we know the Eucildean normal form of A must look something like this
$$\left( \begin{matrix} \pm1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ 0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{matrix} \right)$$
Does this mean we need to find the eigenvalues of $A$ via the characteristic polynomial?
There ought to be a better way of doing this.

How do we find the matrix $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If the matrix is proper,i.e., has determinant $1$, there is a much easier approach using [Rodrigues formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_angle#Log_map_from_SO.283.29_to_so.283.29). For nonproper case, do the same for $-A$.

Comment: I've determined that the upper left entry of $B$ must be $1$: We have that $Trace(A) = Trace(B) = \sqrt 3 + 1$. Now if the upper left entry were $-1$, then the other two diagonal elements must add up to $sqrt 3 + 2$ which cannot be since they're both $\leq 1$. So $A$ is proper and by the Rodrigues formula $$B = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt 3 /2 & -1/2 \\ 0 & 1/2 & \sqrt 3 /2 \end{matrix} \right)$$ Is that true?

Comment: What about finding an orthogonal matrix $S$ such that $$B=S^{-1}AS$$? How do I go about that?

Comment: @rehband Now you have the rotation axis, it is much easier to rotate it to either x- y- or z- axis,right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean :)

Comment: @rehband It means you can identify the rotation axis of your matrix first. Then you need to rotate your rotation axis to $x$ axis to become your so called normal form. This can be done by rotating the rotation axis to $x$ about their common perpendicular. This operation is in the form of conjugation $S^{-1}(\cdot)S$.